# Webscraping not retrieving entire document urllib or requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urlopen

I am attempting to scrape product information from lowes.com. My test is specifically this product [AirStone 8-sq ft Autumn Mountain Faux Stone Veneer](https://www.lowes.com/pd/AirStone-8-sq-ft-Autumn-Mountain-Faux-Stone-Veneer/50247201). When I visit the page without JavaScript enabled ( to ensure I'm not seeing stuff that urllib / requests may not pick up on ) I clearly get a price for the item yet when I attempt to use either package above I am missing several sections of the web page.

It just so happens those sections are the sections I need for scraping ( price information specifically, everything else magically is still available ). I'd prefer not to use selenium for speeds sake. My current usage for both Requests and urllib look thusly

Common Items

```
from urlopen import Request, urlopen
import requests # switch as needed with urlopen
import gzip # manual deflation required with Request object urlopen or so I've found

url = "https://www.lowes.com/pd/AirStone-8-sq-ft-Autumn-Mountain-Faux-Stone-Veneer/50247201"
headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "DNT": "1",
        # "Host": "www.lowes.com", Tried, no difference
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        # "Referer": "https://www.lowes.com/", Tried, no difference
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1 Win64 x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,"
        " like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" # <=- Tried placing all on one line, didn't make a difference
    }
```

Urlopen

```
req = Request(url, None, headers)
page = gzip.decompress(urlopen(req).read()).decode('utf-8')
with open("content.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(page) # <=- missing the 59.97 price tag anywhere in the document :(
```

Requests

```
sessions = requests.Session()
page = sessions.get(self.url, headers=headers)

with open("content.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(page) # <=- Also missing the 59.97 price tag anywhere in the document :'(
```

So question is, am I missing something? Is there a reason for this to be missing? It isn't javascript related as I intentionally disable it before trying to scrape the data as I saw that was an issue a lot of the time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The page you're getting back says "Enter your location for pricing and availability" - in an actual browser, you probably have a cookie from a previous visit that is providing your location to the website.  I'm sure it's possible to include a cookie with either of your request methods, but I don't know the details.

Comment: That is an amazing catch I thought I had deleted cookies. Apparently I had not. That is very much appreciated good internet dweller :) Tally-Ho to see what I can find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment from jasonharper. Cookies ended up being the answer. Finding the right one allowed me to extract all the data necessary.

In short, always disable / delete cookies before trying to scrape a website if for no other reason than to make sure you see what the script sees.

For those curious the specific cookie is {"sn": "####"} ( store number ) You can simply pick a store and hover over it with javascript enabled look at the url it's linked to to find out the store number. Change to suit